# mysql optimize query where date hour

Tags: mysql, date, where-clause, hour

Hi all, I have pretty awfull query, that needs optimizing.

I need to select all records where date of created matches NOW - 35days, but the minutes and seconds can be any.

So I have this query here, its ugly, but working:

Any optimisation tips are welcome!

```
SELECT * FROM outbound_email
                 oe
                INNER JOIN (SELECT  `issue_id` FROM `issues` WHERE 1 ORDER BY year DESC, NUM DESC LIMIT 0,5) as issues  
                ON oe.issue_id = issues.issue_id
                WHERE 
                    year(created) = year(  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 35 DAY) ) AND
                    month(created) = month(  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 35 DAY) ) AND
                    day(created) = day(  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 35 DAY) ) AND
                    hour(created) = hour(  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 35 DAY) )  
                    AND campaign_id IN (SELECT id FROM campaigns WHERE initial = 1)
```

Comment: Many people have asked for help with optimizing queries here on SO. You might start by looking at some of the questions which are upvoted and answered along with the ones which are downvoted and closed. Common features among the former are schema definitions, explain plans, timings for partialnand full select statements.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the field "created" is a datetime field and is from the issues table? Since you don't need anything else on the issues and campaign table, then you can do the following:

```
SELECT e.* FROM outbound_email e
JOIN issues i ON e.issue_id = i.issue_id
JOIN campaigns c ON c.id = i.campaign_id
WHERE i.created < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 35 DAY)
AND c.initial = 1
```

There's no need to separate the datetime field into years, months...etc.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be saying you want to select all rows from a table where the time they were created was the same hour as it is currently, 35 days ago

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE created BETWEEN
  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (HOUR(now()) - 840) HOUR) AND
  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (HOUR(now()) - 839) HOUR)
```

Why does it work? Curdate gives us today at midnight. We add to this the current hour of the time (e.g. Suppose it's now 5pm we'd add `HOUR(NOW()) which would give us 17, for a time now of 5pm) but we also subtract 840 because that's 35 days * 24 hours a day = 840 hours. Date add will hence add -823 hours to the current date, i.e. 5pm 35 days ago

We make the search a range to get all the records from the hour, the simplest way to specify an hour later is to subtract 839 hours instead of 840

Technically this query will also return records that are bang on 6pm (but not a second later) 35 days ago too because between is inclusive (between 1 and 10 will return 10 also

If this is a problem, change the BETWEEN for `created >= blah AND created < blahblah`

I haven't put the rest of your query in for reasons of clarity

As a side note, the way you did it wasn't bad- you could have simplified things by not having the year/month/day parts, just dropping the time part of the date with `date(created) = date_sub(curdate(), interval 35 day)` which is the year month and day combined as a date, no time element.. BUT it is generally always best to leave table data alone rather than format or convert it just to match a query. If you convert table data then indexes can no longer be used. If you go the extra mile to get your query parameters into the format of the column, and don't convert the table data then indexes on the column can be used